# Why function with reified type parameter should be inlined?

Tags: kotlin, generics

As I understand reified is mostly sugar, and

Java:

```
static <T> boolean isTypeOf(Object o, Class<T> tClass) {
    return tClass.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass());
}
```

Kotlin:

```
inline fun <reified T> Any.isTypeOf(): Boolean = this is T
```

seems to me equivalent, is there any difference?
Why function with reified type parameter should be inlined?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters

Comment: Calls to an inline function copy the function to the call site—that's what it means to be _inlined_. So a call to `obj.isTypeOf<Foo>()` is literally replaced with `obj is Foo`. That's why generic type parameters can be reified for inline functions. Otherwise Kotlin suffers from type erasure the same as Java.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

The JVM does not reify type parameters; they're ‘erased’, which means they're not available at runtime.  To the compiler, `List<String>` and `List<Int>` are two completely different types — but at the bytecode level all the JVM sees is `List`.

(This is partly for historical reasons; early versions of Java did not have generics, and they were later added in such a way as to cause least disruption.)

So without reification, you have no access to any type parameter.  If you cast a value to that type, the compiler warns that it's an unsafe cast — because it can't be checked at runtime.  If you want to do something like checking the type or creating a new instance, you have to do that ‘manually’ (usually by having the caller pass in a `Class` object as a parameter).

Reification is a workaround for type erasure: when the compiler inlines a function, it has access to the type information at the call site, and can substitute it there and then.  That's why you can use the type parameter to cast, access its `Class` object, and other things that simply aren't possible if the function is called in the usual way.

Comment: What I don't understand is why they don't provide a non-inlined version of reification. Make the first parameter KClass and allow it to be inferred (omitted when calling the function). Syntax like this: `fun <T> foo(inferrable type: KClass<T>, bar: String)` Then the function could be used from Java and signature would be reserved, and you wouldn't need to inline it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 You could submit a feature request (if one doesn't already exist for this).

Comment: @Tenfour04 Interesting idea.  For parameterised classes I guess it'd need to add a hidden property as well as a hidden constructor parameter.  And wouldn't it need to be a `KType`, not a `KClass` (to handle nested type parameters, nullability, &c)?

Comment: I didn't give it much thought, but yeah, KType. I was only thinking about it at the function level. I suppose maybe something like this could be possible for class types if you make it a primary constructor parameter.